# No module named pipeline

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, spacy, rasa-nlu

I am trying to train some data in rasa-nlu.

So, I installed anaconda, then rasa-nlu and spacy.

But, whenever I try to run

```
 python -m rasa_nlu.train -c config.json
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Ddrive\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "D:\Ddrive\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "D:\Ddrive\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\train.py", line 65, in <module>
    do_train(config)
  File "D:\Ddrive\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\train.py", line 54, in do_train
    trainer = create_trainer(config)
  File "D:\Ddrive\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\train.py", line 31, in create_trainer
    from trainers.spacy_sklearn_trainer import SpacySklearnTrainer
  File "D:\Ddrive\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\trainers\spacy_sklearn_trainer.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rasa_nlu.extractors.spacy_entity_extractor import SpacyEntityExtractor
  File "D:\Ddrive\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\extractors\spacy_entity_extractor.py", line 7, in <module>
    from spacy.pipeline import EntityRecognizer
ImportError: No module named pipeline
```

I am not able to install pipeline using conda or pip.

Comment: I think it is changed to `pipeline` to [this](http://jwilk.net/software/python-grapevine)

Comment: Tried installing grapevine, but it gives `'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: I installed it from tar.gz, still same error. Any other ideas ?

Comment: @adirohan did you follow the instructions for installing spacy?

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have now installed MITIE instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your `spacy`version is up to date (at the time of this writing this would be 1.7).

http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/backends.html#option-2-spacy-sklearn

You can install the latest version using 
`pip install -U spacy`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

You can install pipe python with following command:
**cmd:-pip install pipe**